# SQL create new columns from group by with time series data

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have a SQL query which returns data grouped by the date and category so it looks like:

| month | animal | actions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | dog | 1 |
| 2020-01 | cat | 3 |
| 2020-02 | dog | 2 |
| 2020-02 | cat | 5 |

I would like to use this data to display a time series chart and therefore need to have one row per month and a column per animal which shows the actions for that animal in that month

e.g

| month | dog_actions | cat_actions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 1 | 3 |
| 2020-02 | 2 | 5 |

I'm sure I've done this before in SQL but can't think how and unable to find any results to tell me. Any pointers?

Comment: Please show your original data and the query you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional aggregation.  Given your description, this is probably what you want:

```
select month,
       count(*) filter (where animal = 'cat') as cat_actions,
       count(*) filter (where animal = 'dog') as dog_actions
from t
group by month;
```

The `count(*)` might actually be some other expression, depending on what your data looks like.